# Adding two fields in php

Tags: php, sql

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM productlist1 order by pdesc ASC");


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
$sold=$row['psold'];
$left=$row['pleft'];
$all=$left + $sold;
  {
    echo '<tr>';

      echo '<td>'.$row['pcode'].'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$row['pdesc'].'</td>';
       echo '<td>'.$row['date'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['time'].'</td>';
      echo '<td><div align="center">'.$row['psold'].'</div></td>';
      echo '<td><div align="center">'.$row['pleft'].'</div></td>';
      echo '<td><div align="center">'.$row['pprice'].'</div></td>';
    echo '<td><div align="center">'.$all.'</div></td>';
```

i want to add the pleft and psold, the $all doesn't work at all... what would i do with this code?

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error. You need to place following 3 lines inside brackets:

```
$sold=$row['psold'];
$left=$row['pleft'];
$all=$left + $sold;
```

like:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $sold=$row['psold'];
  $left=$row['pleft'];
  $all=$left + $sold;
    echo '<tr>';
    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put opening braces for while loop just after the while statement like.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$sold=$row['psold'];
$left=$row['pleft'];
$all=$left + $sold;
  ...............
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your addition inside while loop,

because outside while loop it doesn't work, because it does not get proper value

So , try like this

```
    <?php

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM productlist1 order by pdesc ASC");


    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $all=$row['psold'] + $row['pleft'];
        echo '<tr>';

          echo '<td>'.$row['pcode'].'</td>';
          echo '<td>'.$row['pdesc'].'</td>';
           echo '<td>'.$row['date'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['time'].'</td>';
          echo '<td><div align="center">'.$row['psold'].'</div></td>';
          echo '<td><div align="center">'.$row['pleft'].'</div></td>';
          echo '<td><div align="center">'.$row['pprice'].'</div></td>';
        echo '<td><div align="center">'.$all.'</div></td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM productlist1 order by pdesc ASC");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
    $sold=$row['psold'];
    $left=$row['pleft'];
    $all=$left + $sold;
        echo '<tr>';
          echo '<td>'.$row['pcode'].'</td>';
          echo '<td>'.$row['pdesc'].'</td>';
           echo '<td>'.$row['date'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['time'].'</td>';
          echo '<td><div align="center">'.$row['psold'].'</div></td>';
          echo '<td><div align="center">'.$row['pleft'].'</div></td>';
          echo '<td><div align="center">'.$row['pprice'].'</div></td>';
        echo '<td><div align="center">'.$all.'</div></td>';
echo '</tr>';
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try parsing the values to integer like

```
$all=intval($left)+intval($sold);
```

Yeah one more thing your while is misplaced!!

Comment: why -1 for this answer??